# Plain http proxy via https?

Tags: networking, proxy, bittorrent

I am not very experienced in network related stuff, but latterly I have to dig into it, because the level of censorship in my country is growing rapidly. I am hosting a VPS in another country on which I set up OpenVPN and Shadowsocks services. It is a great tool for bypassing local censorship and having access to forbidden resources, but now I need something more complicated. Recently my ISP has blocked some torrent trackers on which I seed hundreds of torrents. Now my torrent client is not able to announce to those trackers, so I can only seed with DHT. What I want is to use some workarounds for connecting to the blocked trackers, but I don't want to wrap the entire torrent traffic into VPN/Proxy, I want to be able to use some sort of proxy for only making tracker announces and then seed with my real `IP:Port`. I've tried to set up my Deluge client to use Socks5-proxy(Shadowsocks) for tracker connections only, but it doesn't work as expected, because the trackers get my VPS' IP, not my real one. Then I found a working method - I set up Nginx in proxy_pass mode on my VPS this way:

```
http {
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        access_log off;
        return 444;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <trackers_list>;
        allow <my_home_ip>;
        deny  all;
        access_log off;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$http_host;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            resolver 127.0.0.1;
        }
    }
}
```

In my router's settings I forwarded all requests to the blocked trackers to the port 80 of my remote VPS. Now it works fine - I can announce to the trackers via proxy, but the trackers then give my real IP to peers with the help of the `X-Forwarded-For` header, and DHT is not broken. But the problem is that it looks like this:

```
Me -> http -> ISP -> http -> Nginx -> http -> tracker
```

Because of the trackers use plain http protocol, the entire requests are unencrypted. Thus, the ISP, if wanted to, can still see the real destination of the requests and block them with something like DPI. What I want is it to be like this:

```
Me -> https -> ISP -> https -> Nginx -> http -> tracker
```

I want Nginx to proxy plain http requests to the trackers with the addition of the `X-Forwarded-For` headers, but use encryption between my home machine and itself. I've tried to naively tell Nginx to use my self-signed SSL certificate on port 80, but, obviously, I get the 400 error in that way: `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`.

Is it possible to achieve? If not with Nginx, maybe, with any other tools?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to resolve this with reverse proxy or the like, but you could do a ssh port forwarding.
So you keep a ssh connection to your vps and configure ssh to forward a local port to the port of the tracker. Then, you configure your torrent application to use the localhost address:port instead of the real trackers address.

Like `ssh –L 8080:the.tracker.ip:trackerport user@your.vps.address` and then have the tracker configured as `http://localhost:8080` in the torrent application.
Or any other local port you like.

Depending on your OS you can use tools like putty or https://github.com/daradib/sidedoor the latter keeping the tunnel open and reconnecting automatically on interruption.
The ssh tunnel will then encrypt all communication serve through it.

Edit: that works only if the torrent application determines the public IP address itself somehow and not when the tracker simply uses the IP address where the connection seems to come from.